# Firmware upgrade from Azure IoT HuB

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I have an instrument which has USB output. My application will connect the instrument over COM port and read/write the data. Instrument has Bluetooth module as well, Bluetooth will help to upgrade the firmware. I'm migrating to Azure IoT Hub. Now my application is capable of sending message to IoT Hub. Now I want to send firmware to Device (in my case it's not direct edge device, application will receive the command/firmware and then send it to the instrument/device).
I tested Cloud to Device it's working fine, however I don't know how to push firmware from Azure IoT hub. Any suggestion please.

I have tested Azure IoT Hub "Cloud to Device" it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete tutorial/sample on how you could do Over the Air Update with IoT Hub: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-firmware-update

Of course, the exact implementation depends on lot on your actual devices.

Comment: Thank you. Do we have .Net examples?

Comment: SimulatedDevice.js stuck in client.open() not triggering twin.on at all. Any advise please..

Comment: how exactly do you expect anybody could help you with that error description? (plus, it would be a new question on SO, where you would post relevant parts of your code, error messages, etc.)